# define an element as a list of another element in xml schema

Tags: xml, xsd, social-networking

I want to define a smaple XML Schema for a social network website.I've defined a Person element and it's related attributes and other child elements.it's a part of the schema which I've defined. :

```
<xs:element name="Person" type="Person" />
    <xs:complexType name="Person">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="firstName" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="lastName" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="nickName" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="age" >
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                      <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                      <xs:maxInclusive value="120"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="birthDate" type="xs:date"/>
            <xs:element name="gender" type="Gender" />
            <xs:element name="contactDetails" type="ContactInfo"/>
            <xs:element name="occupation" type="Occupation" /> 
        </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

now I want to define another child for Person as it's friends but I dont know how can I do this.does any body have any Idea about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work for you:

```
  <xs:element name="Persons">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Person" type="PersonType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="uniquePersonId">
      <xs:selector xpath="./Persons"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@PersonID"/>
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="PersonType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="firstName" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="lastName" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name = "Friends" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Friend" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:complexType >
                <xs:attribute name="FriendId" type="xs:IDREF" use="required" />
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="PersonID" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: thank you very much,how can I define the relation ship with diferent person,for example mutual friends of two person?

Comment: I don't know to be honest. I'm not sure that should be defined in the schema, that could be one thing you find out in code using Linq to xml for example.

Comment: I edited my answer so a person has an id and has a sequence of friends identified by ids.